# Detect lines and its curve hand drawn by Graphics2d in a java draw application

Tags: java, user-interface, detection, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I'm making a music application that enables you to freedraw lines from specified colors and then a trackbar would pass on top of it and should detect the curves and color to output sound and modified pitch etc depending on the curves.

What I'm looking for is help on detecting the lines and curves. They are drawn in a Label as a BUfferedImage. The following is a screenshot:

[image: GUI Of drawing/music aplication]

The Black line I drew to represent the trackbar, but infact it would be a Rectangle drawn by drawRect or it could be a imagepanel, depends on the way you detect lines.

My question:

- How could I detect the yellow, green, etc lines and its curve and handle that data? If I get that data I could easily modify gain and pitch for each assign sound for each color. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to store the coordinates of the user's drawing motions at the very least. You could store these as points or convert them into representations of line segments and/or curves depending on your requirements. Of course, store the stroke, color and anything you want as part of this model.

To accomplish this, I think the path of least resistance would probably have you utilizing `java.awt.Shape` and everything in `java.awt.geom`. Specifically, I think you would want to represent each user-drawn element as one or more `Path2D` and/or `Area` objects in response to user drawing motions. Then, have your GUI render these models on your custom Component.

Path2D would store the movements as lines and curves accessible through a PathIterator. Given a trackbar represented by a `Rectangle2D`, you can use the various methods available for comparing and combining geometries--namely the Shape interface's `intersects(Rectangle2D)` here. If a geometry model intersects your trackbar, you could then iterate through the path components until you find the actual sub-segment that is intersecting. This gets you the local slope.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This gave me an idea on how I would do this, I will read on the libraries and see where I can get to!